# use data types or other library-specific variables as arguments in hydra

Tags: python, python-3.x, fb-hydra, omegaconf

I would like to use python datatypes - both built-in and imported from libraries such as numpy, tensorflow, etc - as arguments in my hydra configuration.
Something like:

```yaml
# config.yaml

arg1: np.float32
arg2: tf.float16
```

I'm currently doing this instead:

```yaml
# config.yaml

arg1: 'float32'
arg2: 'float16
```

```py
# my python code
# ...
DTYPES_LOOKUP = {
  'float32': np.float32,
  'float16': tf.float16
}
arg1 = DTYPES_LOOKUP[config.arg1]
arg2 = DTYPES_LOOKUP[config.arg2]
```

Is there a more *hydronic*/elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the [`hydra.utils.get_class`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/abb36af33e83f391a22d6269fd2f317378171ec9/hydra/utils.py#L21) function solve this problem for you?

```yaml
# config.yaml

arg1: numpy.float32  # note: use "numpy" here, not "np"
arg2: tensorflow.float16
```

```py
# python code
...
from hydra.utils import get_class
arg1 = get_class(config.arg1)
arg2 = get_class(config.arg2)
```

#### Update 1: using a custom resolver

Based on miccio's comment below, here is a demonstration using an [OmegaConf custom resolver](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_resolvers.html) to wrap the `get_class` function.

```py
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
from hydra.utils import get_class

OmegaConf.register_new_resolver(name="get_cls", resolver=lambda cls: get_class(cls))

config = OmegaConf.create("""
# config.yaml

arg1: "${get_cls: numpy.float32}"
arg2: "${get_cls: tensorflow.float16}"
""")

arg1 = config.arg1
arg1 = config.arg2
```

#### Update 2:

It turns out that `get_class("numpy.float32")` succeeds but `get_class("tensorflow.float16")` raises a ValueError.
The reason is that `get_class` checks that the returned value is indeed a class (using `isinstance(cls, type)`).

The function [`hydra.utils.get_method`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/abb36af33e83f391a22d6269fd2f317378171ec9/hydra/utils.py#L32) is slightly more permissive, checking only that the returned value is a callable, but this still does not work with `tf.float16`.

```py
>>> isinstance(tf.float16, type)
False
>>> callable(tf.float16)
False
```

A custom resolver wrapping the `tensorflow.as_dtype` function might be in order.

```py
>>> tf.as_dtype("float16")
tf.float16
```

Comment: Thanks for the high-quality answer as usual! In this case, since I don't want my DNN model to "depend" on hydra, I think I will embed the get_class function inside a custom resolver.

Comment: Great idea r.e. the custom resolver!

Comment: Updated the answer with a caveat regarding `tf.float16`. I've opened a related [feature request](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1975).

Comment: impressive work, thanks again!!